# how to cnfigure WAS Liberty profile with My Eclipse Blue 2014?

Tags: ibm-was

I was using WAS for my app in RAD tool. Since it is costly, I am planning to migrate my application to work on WAS Liberty profile in My Eclipse blue 2014. Could any one of you suggest how to open admin console as we used to in WAS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no admin console for the Liberty Profile. To edit the configuration, you just use a text editor on the configuration file in the profile. If you install MyEclipse 2015 CI, there is an additional option on the context menu for the Liberty Profile, in the Servers view, to edit the configuration, which brings up a specific editor for that task.